# read data from datastore into Google Charts Datatable to plot Graphs

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-visualization, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to read data from the datastore of my Google App Engine Application, populate the google charts Datatable with it then visualize the whole thing into a graph using the source code from the  [google charts example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) which uses Javascript code embedded on the web page.

My issue is with fetching the data. I thought of two ways of doing this: either run the query directly inside the javascript code or run the query from the python code , send the results of that query as a template value to the html code, filter it to get the values I'm interested in and somehow passing the whole thing to the javascript code then diplay the data (looks more complicated). I've tried the first option but it doesn't seem to work. Since i wasn't sure what the URL of my datastore was, I though it was the same as the server which uses it so I passed the URL of my appengine application as a parameter to the query function. I tried to run an SQL query on this but I got an error.
Below are the corresponding JS code (alone) and the whole HTML code

```
function drawVisualization() {

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://davidfirstapp.appspot.com');

  query.setQuery('SELECT ac_current1, ac_voltage1 ORDER BY ac_current1 LIMIT 10');

  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
     alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +     response.getDetailedMessage());
     return;
  }
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  visualization.draw(data, {legend: 'bottom'});
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['linechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var visualization;

    function drawVisualization() {

      var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://davidfirstapp.appspot.com');


      query.setQuery('SELECT ac_current1, ac_voltage1 ORDER BY ac_current1 LIMIT 10');


      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +   response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

     var data = response.getDataTable();
     visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
     visualization.draw(data, {legend: 'bottom'});
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

​

Answer (score 2):

You cant query your own webpage and somehow expect it to connect to the datastore. Your webpage contains your own html output that you defined. Read more about appengine / web applications and how the datastore works.
You need to do the datastore query from the frontend, not the browsers js. Build a table and pass it to the browser where it builds the datatable and chart.

Comment: So do you suggest that I use the second option? Meaning that i run the query from my python code then pass the results (aka the table) to the html code? I find this step a bit complicated. Could you walk me through it?

Comment: yes, thats what im suggesting. its really the only way more than a suggestion :)